# How to revise an exsiting kernel package in OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt

I want to make some revisions to the code of package/kernel/mac80211.
I am new to OpenWrt and after some research, I think I should change the PKG_SOURCE_URL to my own GitHub repository, which is my own copy of /linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.19.120.
So I change package/kernel/mac80211/Makefile like following:

```
PKG_SOURCE_PROTO:=git
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=https://github.com/sheep94lion/openwrt.git
PKG_SOURCE_VERSION:=168bae33318ebd14d8c035b543a2583ea31f9f52
PKG_MIRROR_HASH:=skip

# PKG_SOURCE_URL:=@KERNEL/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.19.120/
# PKG_HASH:=2bafd75da301a30a5f2b98f433b6545d7b58c1fc3af15e9e9aa085df7f9db1d4
```

My question is: am I in the right direction? What is the right/proper way to revise an existing kernel package?

Answer (score 0):

I copy the source files to package/kernel/mac80211/src directory (create the directory first), and then revise Makefile to use local source files instead of downloading and unpack from the official URI.

The revisions in Makefile is as following:

```
# comment out the configurations to download the tarball.
# PKG_SOURCE_URL:=@KERNEL/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.19.120/
# PKG_HASH:=2bafd75da301a30a5f2b98f433b6545d7b58c1fc3af15e9e9aa085df7f9db1d4

# PKG_SOURCE:=backports-$(PKG_VERSION).tar.xz

......

define Build/Prepare
    rm -rf $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    # do not unpack the downloaded tarbar.
    # $(PKG_UNPACK)
    # instead, copy files under src to the build directory.
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
    $(Build/Patch)
```

When I want to release the code, I think I should use the patch.